# Using a function to add to an existing xpath?

Tags: javascript, xpath, automated-tests

I have this example html, for which I have the following xpaths defined in a POM:

```
<button>
    Foo
    <i class="myClass" label="a label">Something</i>
</button>
<button>
    Bar
    <i class="myClass" label="another label">Something</i>
</button>
```

```
class myPage {
    constructor() {
        this.fooButton = () => $('//button[text()=\'Foo\']');
        this.barButton = () => $('//button[text()=\'Bar\']');
    }
}
```

I want to access the inner text from the myClass iframe, but don't want to define new constructor elements for it - feels like repeating code:

```
this.insideSomething = () => $('//button[text()=\'Foo\']/i[text()=\'Something\']');
```

Is there a way to perhaps only define the end of the xpath in its own function? Something like this:

```
somethingText(parentElement) {
     return parentElement + '/i[text()=\'Something\']';
}
```

... so I can call it like this, for example:
`expect(somethingText(MyPage.FooButton).isDisplayed()).to.be.true;`

Answer (score 0):

You could try using the "starts with" attribute selector operator `^=`:

```
this.fooButton = () => $('//button[text()^=\'Foo\']');
```

[More info on attribute selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors)

Comment: I'm not sure how this helps my selector be specific to the parent as well as looking for the child?

Comment: I guess I wasn't clear on what you were asking.  This will let you select a Foo button regardless of what `<i>` it contains.